# Regex matching contiguous curly brackets

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to match some curly bracket in HTML for custom built client side templating using regex. I have got it working except in the one case there are 2 or more matching strings next to each other.

The string I am trying to match is:

```
{{+ANYTEXT}}
```

the regex being used is:

```
{{\s*\+\S*\s*}}
```

So the following example:

```
<div class="rows"> 
    {{#Rows}} ssss1212XXXX {{+Anything.More.Evenmore}}$ssds {{/Rows}} 
</div> 
<div class="actions"> 
    {{#Actions}} ss[{{+UI.Action1}} {{+UI.Action2}} sdfsf {{/Actions}} 
    {{#Actions}} sss{{+UI.Action3}}{{+UI.Action4}} sdfsf {{/Actions}} 
</div>
```

Matches the first instance: {{+Anything.More.Evenmore}}; The next 2 actions as individual matches, Action1 and Action2 **BUT** matches the last 2 actions as one match.

So I have trying to figure how to match {{+ANYTEXT}} with anything except } and { at either end but not include them in the match. Unfortunately I have failed. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use a parser, not regex and many of your problems will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex :

```
({{\s*\+[^}]*\s*}})
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tX3eI0)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/L3CX9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add a question mark to the `\S*` to make it less greedy and it works. [Test](http://regex101.com/r/pX9nY3)

```
/{{\s*\+\S*?\s*}}/g
```

Comment: This also works - is there a difference between the previous answer and this one on efficiency?

Comment: Ignoring the bracket matching, which isn't needed on the answer above, I don't think so.